# Shadow and stroke on transparent image in ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have ImageButton that have an icon inside.
The ImageButton and icon background are transparent.

i would like to know how can i add shadow to the icon ? the shadow should be able to be ON/OFF.

if anyone can help with stroke as well i will appreciate it very much.

this is my imageButton -

```
            <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/icon"
                            android:layout_width="140dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_weight="0.76"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:onClick="showIconSelector"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_0" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a drawable for this.  Here is an example of a rectangle with a gradient, a stroke, and rounded corners.  There are lots of possibilities using these:

This would be placed in your drawable folder, then can be referenced the same way you would reference any drawable resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#5C5858" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <gradient
      android:startColor="#C0C0C0"
      android:endColor="#808080"
      android:angle="-90" /> 
</shape>
```

To make this work with On\Off state, you will need to create a selector, that uses different drawables for each state you want to account for.